# const-reference binding to a temporary

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following:

```
string const& name1 = get_name(...);
string const  name2 = get_name(...);
```

where `get_name` returns a `string` object.  As is well known, with the introduction of move-semantics in C++11, both statements can be efficient, with the first one being slightly more so since a move does not need to be made.  (Yeah, I know about return-value optimization, so it's slightly more nuanced.  But this is the general idea.)

However, suppose function calls are left out of this:

```cpp
string const& name3 {"Billy"};
string const  name4 {"Debbie"};
```

In this case, the string-literal `"Billy"` is implicitly converted to a temporary `string`, and `name3` binds to the temporary.  Obviously, `name4` is not a temporary.

Is it true that for `name3` and `name4`, both are equally efficient?  Seems to me that it would be...

Comment: Seems to you that it would be...what? For `name3`, a temporary `string` will be constructed from the literal `"Billy"` and then bound to `name3`, for `name4`, it (i.e. `string`) will be constructed from the literal `"Debbie"` directly.

Comment: I'd argue that you're going into areas of premature optimization here and should choose the one that's clearer (in my opinion the non-reference) unless you actually measured that to be a bottleneck.

Comment: I would expect same generated code (even in lower optimization level).

Comment: Put your code in a function, that function into a file, and `g++ -g -c -Wa,-alh foo.cpp`

Comment: There is no efficiency to be gained here. Are you creating those strings 10000 times in the tightest of all loops? Than you should not. Otherwise, the impact is non-measurable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name3` and `name4` are indistinguishable by the rest of the program, unless you specifically use `decltype(name3)` or `decltype(name4)`.

So the compiler can generate the same assembly for both cases.

Of course, this is a general statement; any individual compiler may generate slower or faster code and the only way to find out is to try it on that compiler.

Comment: @KyleKnoepfel I didn't mean that .  `decltype((name3))` is the same as `decltype((name4))`  however `decltype(name3)` differs from  `decltype(name4)`.